# Best way working with trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I wan't to compute some trigonometric formulas. 
Is better to simplify as much as I could my formulas ?
Examples:

```
Ex. 1: u = atan2(cos(pi/4), sin(pi/4)*cos(0))/(2*pi)
Ex. 2: u = atan((pi/4)/cos(pi/4))/(2*pi)
```

These examples give me two different outputs, although in theory, both of them return the same result.
So, what is the best way to work such formulas ?

Comment: note the range for `atan`: over a period of `2pi` it'll hit each value twice, meaning you cannot ambiguate half of your cases - that's exactly what `atan2` is for.

Comment: but, i'm interested in how you will get the most precise result after combining multiple trigonometric functions.

Comment: the biggest issue in my question is floating numbers fractional limit
because of that I want to take advantage of this trigonometric functions as much as I could to get the most accurate result.

Comment: Precision for these operations are comparable to other arithmetic floating point operations. Maybe one rule of thumb might help: reducing the amount of floating point operations also reduces the amount of floating point error in your terms. So reducing `2x` to `x` operations roughly halves your error term.

Comment: thank you !
I'll take that in consideration when I start coding them :-)